# how to find the type of integer from a file using java

Tags: java, file-io

I have a file that contains integer values of different bit lengths (4 bytes, 2 bytes), but I don't know the layout of these values in the file (i.e. whether a value is a 4 bytes or 2 bytes integer).  For example, a file may have two 4-byte integers followed by five 2-byte integers, and another file may have three 2-byte integers first and then four 4-byte integers.  Is there a way to read such values?

I want to write code that takes such a file and reads a value irrespective of its byte size.  Right now I am using `DataInputStream`, and by knowing the layout of the values, using some viewer in advance to read the values.  But in this manner everything is hard coded, and my code is not generic.

Comment: How would you tell the difference between two 2 byte integers and one 4 byte integer?

Comment: That's totally impossible.  Bytes are bytes.

Comment: I'd start finding the original author of the file format and ask him/her.

Comment: this was exactly my doubt..since i am just a beginner and trying to learn java programming, i thought there could be some way and i may not be able to find it out..thanks all of you for the response

Comment: can you be more experessive? mind sharing some content from the file? most of the time people ask question without thinking about the real problem. The problem which appears to them is an illusion to the basic problem they might have ignored. 

And yes, how would you diffrentiate between a 4 byte or 2 byte integer. or more precisely, what difference these 4 byte/2byte integer would make on your business logic? If you explain more then it would be easier to analyse and answer.

Comment: the file contains integer values for predefined fields.each field has got its fixed position but the byte size of the value for a particular field is not fixed.for example, at the first position the file has a field named "JOB ID" and it has "102" as its value, then it has "NO.OF RECORDS" and its value is "1501", then it has "INTERVAL" and its value is "4" and so on..the file contains only these values and not the fields(as the position of each field is always fixed).

Comment: if i am not reading the values according to their byte size, then i may read 2 bytes of a 4 bytes integer by mistake and take it as a valid value and the next 2 bytes of the same number as the next value.as a result i will end up reading all wrong values.

Comment: apologies if my question looks illogical

Comment: When you say "...some viewer in advance to read the values..." tells me this "viewer" knows the file format.  Is this true?  If so, tell us more about the "viewer".

Comment: yes, the viewer knows the file format.it's called "seisee" and is developed for viewing seismic data.we can load a seismic file through the UI and the viewer shows all the values in a table format along with the corresponding fields(though the fields are not present in the file, it is just for the sake of convenience).

Comment: Then your going to have to "parse" or "read" or "do something" with the viewer data and use the refactored viewer info as file format data.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to "parse" or "read" or "do something" with the viewer data and use the refactored viewer info as file format definition info during the reads.